# Unable to connect using sql authentication through an asp.net web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I cannot get my web app to connect to the database when running the app. I can connect in the SQL Server object explorer and I took the connection string from the connections properties

Here is my connection string :

```
<add name="Quotes.DAL.QuotesConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=***;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I can connect as `SA` and I can create the database that it points to in Management Studio. When my app tries to connect via Entity Framework I get the following error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,

I'm running Windows 7 as a home dev machine so there is no Active Directory.

Can anybody explain why this might happen?

I have found that this is probably because I have Entity Framework in another assembly. I created a new web application and its connection string works. When it try the same connection string in my DAL it fails with this same error!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a server certificate? You have set this up with TrustServerCertificate = False. If you have no verifiable certificate the connection attempt will raise an exception. I suspect you probably should just remove the TrustServerCertificate section in the connection string.

Comment: Here is a link that explains that setting. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. i tried to remove this. it does not make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried looking at connectionstrings.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It may be because of setting `Integrated Security=False`, I have never set it to false.</strike>  I normally use just the bare minimum `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;` when setting up my connection strings with sql authentication, only adding things as I need them.

The other issue I see is using SA to connect to the database.  This breaks almost every best practice in the book and I would recommend creating an app specific password for when you roll out the program.  The reason being is the *GOD ACCESS* account for the server will have its password in plain text in the app.config file.  Just something to keep in mind.

EDIT: After some comment discussion the connection string was in the wrong config file.

Comment: hi i am using this connection string to test as i get this error when connecting using windows authentication. I would not normally use sa i just want to find a solution. i have found that this is probably because i have entity framework in another assembly. i created a new web application and its connection string works. when it try the same connection string in my DAL it fails with this same error!

Comment: @Paul  Are you putting the connection string in the app.config that is created in the DAL.dll project?

Comment: yes i put the connection string in the app config of the DAL assembly. i have no connection strings in the UI project. could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes you will need to put the connection string into the UI project.  This is confusing sometimes but true.

Comment: @Paul  Yes that is the problem.  All the EF app config information needs to go in the web.config (or app.config of the executable).  Otherwise it does not get picked up.  You also need to add the EF dll's (nuget package) to the web app (or exe).

Comment: Thanks this has helped solve my problem. i did not know i still had forgotton to remove my connection string from the web.config (i just added my code to tfs online and was trying to get it to work on a second machine) as i did not change the connection string in the UI project as well as the DAL project it was throwing an error for the UI project which was using windows authentication to another server